# How to configure jenkins slack plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack, slack-api

I tried to configure jenkins slack plugin to send a notification to slack channel. But it doesn't work. I followed below instruction:

```
1. Get a Slack account: https://slack.com/
2. Configure the Jenkins integration: https://my.slack.com/services/new/jenkins-ci
3. Install this plugin on your Jenkins server.
4. Configure it in your Jenkins job (and optionally as global configuration) and add it as a Post-build action.
```

After I install `jenkins` on slack app there is a instruction about how to configure jenkins. But the configuration fields mentioned on the instruction is a little different than my jenkins configuration.

Below is the configuration screenshot from the instruction:

[image]

the configuration for my jenkins server looks like below:

[image]

how can I fill in the `Base URL` in my configuration? I have tried to fill in my `jenkins url` but it doesn't work. The test connection failed.

I get below error in jenkins system log:

```
Slack post may have failed. Response: <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2FOPRc9G4zB2JX289VOnTvfeey'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2FOPRc9G4zB2JX289VOnTvfeey');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

I have tried to leave base url empty but still doesn't work

Comment: Have you noticed the Base Sever URL in this link "https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226460047-How-do-I-configure-Slack-Plugin-".
Have you configured it in your Jenkins and tried run test?

Comment: I have tried to set my jenkins url  in the link but it doesn't work. I tried to run `test` connection but always got failed result.

Comment: I have left the Base URL as blank and tried the test connection it got success have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried but still got `failure`.

Comment: what other parameters are you setting?

Comment: Team Subdomain, Integration Token and channel.
Check your token and domain name once and try.

Comment: I have tried to regenerate the token but still not working.

Comment: Have You using Token Credentials ID in configuration??

Comment: I tried both, `Integration Token Credential ID ` and `Integration Token`. None of them work.

Comment: When you hit on test connection have you got any failure message there?

Comment: I have checked jenkins system log and found an error there. I have added on the post. Do you have any idea on this error? It seems that it uses anonymous user.

Comment: There is no other messages on testing connection

Comment: Channel you are using is configured according to the Jenkins and you are admin for that??

Your got Struck at the Global configuration only right??

Comment: Please try this configuration.I have following Configuration for my slack channel:
**Base URL**: https://example.slack.com/services/hooks/jenkins-ci/
**Team Subdomain**: example
**Integration Token**: TOKEN generated for Jenkins-CI in slack
**Is BOT-User**: unchecked
**Channel**: #Slack channel Name

Comment: I have tried but still failed. I also tried to add `https://` and `http://` in front of your base url.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing, I figured out the problem. The issue relates to the configuration panel for slack. When I change the slack configuration and hit the test button, it doesn't take the current configuration, instead, it takes the previously saved configuration. I have to save the configuration first then test the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Base URL doesn't need to be filled. Try from Specific Project. Only supply Team SubDomain in Global setting.
You have to provide these info separately for every project:

> Team Domain/Sub-Domain 
>   Integration Token(Taken from the Browse Apps > Jenkins CI) 
>   Channel Name

For each Project that you would like receive notifications for, choose Configure from the project's menu in Jenkins.

You'll also need to add Slack Notifications to the Post-build Actions for this project.
Provide the Channel name, Team Subdomain and Integration Token there.
Test the connection.

Comment: I have tried post build action for slack but still not able to send slack notification. It failed to connect slack with the `authentication` error in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly run a POST build shell script per project basis or per slack channel

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "'"$SLACK_MSG"'"}' $SLACK_WEB_HOOK_URL
```

where $SLACK_WEB_HOOK_URL and $SLACK_MSG can be exported as env variables or hardcode it for each project

Answer (score 0):

Hay, 
you have to add you integration Token to your Jenkins(I would recommend to add a Credential ID but its not necessary), that should sole your Problem. Keep in mind that your Jenkins just can send Messages to channels, the Account which generated the token has access to.

As said previously, you dont have to add a Team-Domain and your Subdomain has to be the following part of your Slack link:

www.EXAMPLE.slack.com

Hopefully i was able to help